# Accessing an external variable from a C library

Tags: dynamic-linking, dynamic-library

I am currently learning C and am trying to understand the possibilities of dynamic libraries.
My current question is, if I have a simple "Hello World" application in C called "ProgA", and this program dynamically loads a shared library with some example code called "LibB", can LibB access a global variable in ProgA, which was declared as `external`?

Given is the following example code for demonstration of the problem:

**file `header.h`**

```
#ifndef TEST_H
#define TEST_H

typedef struct test_import_s {
    int some_field;
} test_import_t;

extern test_import_t newtestimport;

#endif
```

**file `prog_a.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "header.h"

test_import_t newtestimport = {
    .some_field = 42
};

int main()
{
    HINSTANCE hinstLib;
    typedef void (*FunctionPointer)();

    newtestimport.some_field = 42;

    hinstLib = LoadLibrary("lib_b.dll");
    if (hinstLib != NULL)
    {
        FunctionPointer initialize_lib_b;
        initialize_lib_b = (FunctionPointer)GetProcAddress(hinstLib, "initialize_lib_b");

        if (initialize_lib_b != NULL)
        {
            initialize_lib_b();
        }

        FreeLibrary(hinstLib);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**file `lib_b.c`**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "header.h"

test_import_t *timp;

void initialize_lib_b() {
    timp = &newtestimport;
    int some_field = timp->some_field;
    printf("Result from function: %d\n", some_field);
}
```

**file `CMakeLists.txt`**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.24)
project(dynamic-library-2 C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 23)

add_library(lib_b SHARED lib_b.c)

set_target_properties(lib_b PROPERTIES PREFIX "" OUTPUT_NAME "lib_b")

add_executable(prog_a prog_a.c)

target_link_libraries(prog_a lib_b)
```

In the above example, the headerfile `header.h` defines the struct `test_import_t` and an `external` variable `newtestimport` using this struct. In the C file of the main program `prog_a.c` one property of this struct is assigned the value `42`. It then dynamically loads the library `lib_b.c` using the Windows API and executes a function in it. The function then should access the variable `newtestimport` of the main program and print out the value of the variable (42).

This example does not work. The compiler throws the following error:

```
====================[ Build | prog_a | Debug ]==================================
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\223.8617.54\bin\cmake\win\x64\bin\cmake.exe --build C:\Users\user1\projects\learning-c\cmake-build-debug --target prog_a -j 9
[1/2] Linking C shared library dynamic-library-2\lib_b.dll
FAILED: dynamic-library-2/lib_b.dll dynamic-library-2/liblib_b.dll.a
cmd.exe /C "cd . && C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\223.8617.54\bin\mingw\bin\gcc.exe -fPIC -g  -Wl,--export-all-symbols -shared -o dynamic-library-2\lib_b.dll -Wl,--out-implib,dynamic-library-2\liblib_b.dll.a -Wl,--major-image-version,0,--minor-image-version,0 dynamic-library-2/CMakeFiles/lib_b.dir/lib_b.c.obj  -lkernel32 -luser32 -lgdi32 -lwinspool -lshell32 -lole32 -loleaut32 -luuid -lcomdlg32 -ladvapi32 && cd ."
C:\Users\user1\AppData\Local\JetBrains\Toolbox\apps\CLion\ch-0\223.8617.54\bin\mingw\bin/ld.exe: dynamic-library-2/CMakeFiles/lib_b.dir/lib_b.c.obj:lib_b.c:(.rdata$.refptr.newtestimport[.refptr.newtestimport]+0x0): undefined reference to `newtestimport'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

How can the example be fixed to accomplish the described goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Windows DLLs are *self-contained*, and can not have undefined references similar to `newtestimport`, *unless* these references are satisfied by another DLL.

> How can the example be fixed to accomplish the described goal?

The best fix is to pass the address of `newtestimport` into the function that needs it (`initialize_lib_b()` here).

If for some reason you can't do that, your next best option is to define the `newtestimport` as a `dllexport` variable in another DLL, e.g. `lib_c.dll`.

Then both the main executable and `lib_b.dll` would be linked against `lib_c.lib`, and would both use that variable from `lib_c.dll`.

P.S. Global variables are a "code smell" and a significant source of bugs. You should avoid them whenever possible, and in your example there doesn't seem to be any good reason to use them.